# HtmlTemplate loading after ajax request complete in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am currently working in Angular2 and I am clueless about certain aspect of angular2, So my question is I have worked with jquery and html there I used to load html template in response of jquery ajax using HTML template and then append template to the view , Now How can I achieve same thing in Angular2. My scenario is that, I have a typescript class which has an associated html page which handle a checkbox onChange event and in success response of that event I want to append an HTML to current element.

- How to create dynamic template.
- How to bind event to dynamically created template with handler in my previously created typescript class.
- How to render it under the current html elment.

Comment: Where from the dynamic template contents will come? Do you want to use a checkbox to append some content after the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery you would use javascript to append any response you would like on to the DOM. In angular2 it works slightly differently - your HTML itself is responsive to changes in the typescript side of the code. So in your example, this would look as such:

```
<html>
<div id='checkboxList'>
<span> Please check here for change </span>
  <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleCheck($event)" />
<div *ngIf='response'>{{response}}</div>
</div>
</html>
```

and in your component linked to this html:

```
response = null;
 toggleCheck(event)
    {
        this.MyService.getGridData(parameters).subscribe(
            result => {
              this.response = result;
            }
        );
    }
```

So in terms of having a dynamic template in your HTML, that's what the {{}} are for - they link to the variable in the typescript and when that is filled (when you subscribe) it will display in the HTML.

Comment: I have tried this but it shows only the response as object , But i want a new HTML template which create sub checkbox with check event bind.

Comment: All this is possible with the correct binding. You could have a checkbox that is hidden until your data is returned, but I'm not sure what you want to do.  If you post the exact data you are sending and expect to see, that would be helpful.